# Python memory profiler gives different results for different runs

Tags: python, memory-profiling

I'm using `%memit` on google colab to get the memory usage of a backward process. I think the results should be exactly the same for each run. But I got different results. This is my results in MiB:

```
98.93, 98.98, 122.41, 98.92, 122.34, 98.80, 122.55
```

All I did is:

```
mem = %memit -o loss.backward(retain_graph = False)
```

I don't know why the results are different. I even restart the kernel every time before I run. Does the variance come from `%memit` or from `backward` process?

Comment: How did you get %memit to work in google colab? When I tried it, I got "Line magic function `%memit'` not found."

Comment: @EEE Try adding `!pip install memory_profiler` and `%load_ext memory_profiler`.

Comment: Ahh. Thanks, @M.Z.